# How do I write data in every last column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to add a new column everyday and the data insertion will be done individually  for the specific row comparing with the input... please tell me if it is correct or not.

[image: this is my sheet]

will this piece of code work for adding new columns ever day and initialize all the entries by 0?

```
    function trig(){

    var builder = ScriptApp.newTrigger("addcol").timeBased().everyDays(1);
     var trigger = builder.create();
   }


   function addcol(){

     var cname = builder.atDate( day, month, year)
     var column = eventRange.getLastColumn();
     sheet.insertColumnAfter(column).setName(cname);
     sheet.getRange("E1").setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('d/M/yyyy');
     var col = [];
     for(var n=0 ; n<s.getMaxRows();n++){
       col.getLastColumn().push(['0']);
     }
     ss.getRange('N:N').setValues(col); 
   }
```

// now for the insertion part

here the sr will be compared to SRN from the sheet (E) and if it matches it will replace 0 with 1 in the last column added everyday. plese tell me will this work?

```
    function doPost(e){

    var action = e.parameter.action;

    if(action == 'scanner'){
      return scanner(e);

    }

    }


    function scanner(e){

    var srn = e.parameter.sr;
    var C = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var R = sheet.getLastRow();



    for(i=1; i<=R; i++)
    {
      if (srn == sheet.getDataRange([i][2]))
      {
        sheet.getDataRange([i],[C]).push[(1)];
        sheet.append([i],[C]);
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
        break;
      }
      }


    }
```

Comment: Is your question "will this work"? Did you try to make it work? If it didn't, did you get any error? I see you are using HTML Service. Is it relevant to your issue? There are many errors in your code, but you should better explain what you are trying to accomplish in order to get help.

Comment: @Iamblichus want it to work something like this;  > I want it to add new column automatically every day with all the entries initialized with 0 except all the first row. >then everyday entry will be done (sr is the variable taken from the app) > this entry of sr  will be compared to the SRN column and if the sr matches to the SRN of lets say 3rd row of column B, so the last column which was initialized by 0 should be overwriten by 1  but for that row itself. so if it matches with (3,2) it should alter (3,lastcolumn) by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Time-based trigger:

There are no event objects associated with time-based triggers, so variables like `eventRange` cannot work. It seems like you want to use variables in `addcol` that are defined in `trig` (e.g. `builder`). That is not possible. Also, if you want your function to run once a day, there is no need for lines like this: `builder.atDate(day, month, year)`). The trigger will be created by running this function once:

```js
function createTrigger(){
  var builder = ScriptApp.newTrigger("addcol").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
}
```

#### Adding column with 0's:

There are many problems with the function `addcol`:

- Several uninitialized variables are being used (`s`, `builder`, `eventRange`).
- Unexisting methods are being used: e.g.: [setNumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormat(String)) is a method of the Range class, not of the `Date` object. You should use [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) to format dates. Also, you are using `setName` when inserting a new column, but that changes the sheet name. Is that what you want to do? And also, `cname` is assigned a trigger builder as value, which I seriously doubt is your purpose. The same way, an array `col` does not have a method `getLastColumn()`.

You could use this `addcol` function instead (change your sheet name, currently set to `Your sheet name`, and the `timeZone` in `formatDate`, currently set to `GMT`:

```js
function addcol() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Your sheet name"); // Change accordingly
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (sheet.getMaxColumns() === lastCol) sheet.insertColumnAfter(lastCol);
  var newCol = sheet.getRange(1, lastCol + 1, lastRow, 1);
  var values = [];
  values.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "d/M/yyyy")]); // Change accordingly
  for (var i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    values.push([0]);
  }
  newCol.setValues(values);
}
```

#### Replacing 0's with 1's:

Assuming that you are getting the function `scanner` to run correctly and that the parameter `e.parameter.sr` is getting populated correctly, you can do the following:

```js
function scanner(e){
  var srn = e.parameter.sr;
  var C = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var R = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (i=1; i<=R; i++) {
    if (srn == sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue()) {
      sheet.getRange(i, C).setValue(1);
    }
  }    
}
```

Here you were also using unexisting methods or providing incorrect parameters:

- The method `getDataRange` doesn't allow any argument, you should be using [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column), and provide the row and column indexes separated by commas, not as if trying to access a 2D array.
- `break` terminates the current loop, so only use it if you only want to update 1 cell. The same goes for `return` which finishes current function execution.

#### Reference:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out.. i just need one more favor please.. when i run this script it shows this.. "The script completed but did not return anything." i thought there must be some errors in my android program but there is not.

Comment: @NinjA1509 Add `return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");` after ending the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

**Short**

No

**Long**

There are several problems with the script:

1. `getDataRange()` expects no arguments passed (docs only say it is the *same* as using `getRange(yourSheet.getLastRow(), yourSheet.getLastColumn())`, not that you should do it). Certainly it does not expect instances of `Array` (bracket `[]` notation wraps `C` and `i`, which are of type `Number` into one). Moreover, it returns a `Range`, which at the time of writing does not have `push()` method.
2. `getLastColumn()` returns an instance of `Number`, and thus does not have a `push()` method as well. You are on the right track, though, since `col` is an `Array`, and you need to `push()` into it.
3. If you want the script to add a zero-filled column, don't get constant ranges: in current state, `getRange('N:N')` guarantees that each time you will re-initialize column N. Btw, same goes for `getRange("E1")`.
4. You still haven't addressed issues listed in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903807/looping-in-order-to-compare-in-rows-and-columns#comment107759010_60903807) to your previous question.
5. Also, in your `scanner` function there is a syntax error: `push[(1)]` should be `push([1])`.
6. Also, the `sheet` variable is either undeclared or is declared globally, [which is bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

**Notes**

1. If you don't expect number of students to change dynamically, you can switch from `getMaxRows()` to `getLastRow()` to only zero-fill cells that are in range of cureent student info grid.
2. This question is [a direct continuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903807/looping-in-order-to-compare-in-rows-and-columns) of a currently closed one (please, always disclose that for reference at least).
3. How about **skipping** init to zero step at all? If cell is empty, `getValue()` / `getValues()` will return its value as an empty string, which is a *falsy* value, just as `0` is. If you want to count attendance at the end of period, a simple conditional will suffice to sum up.
4. The default MIME type for `TextOutput` instance obtained by `createTextOutput()` is plain text, so setting it to `ContentService.MimeType.TEXT` is an overkill in your case.

**Reference**

1. `getDataRange()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
2. `getLastColumn()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastcolumn)
3. `getValue()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
4. `getValues()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
5. `Range` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
6. `createTextOutput()` [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service#createTextOutput(String))
7. Falsy values explanation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: should i be declaring sheet under a function ? will it be a good practice? and what should i be using if not getDataRange() . Sir, can u please help me out if you understand what am i trying to achieve here?

Comment: i want it to work something like this; > I want it to add new column automatically every day with all the entries initialized with 0 except all the first row. >then everyday entry will be done (sr is the variable taken from the app) > this entry of sr will be compared to the SRN column and if the sr matches to the SRN of lets say 3rd row of column B, so the last column which was initialized by 0 should be overwriten by 1 but for that row itself. so if it matches with (3,2) it should alter (3,lastcolumn) by 1.

Comment: Hi @NinjA1509, yes this is best practice to declare vars locally (and it will help you in the future). As for `getDataRange()` - that's ok, I just pointed out that you are using it not according to specs (there should be no arguments)

Comment: Apart from what I mentioned, if you address issues listed in @lamblichus's answer, you should be likely good to go